# How to read Custom Attributes using reflection set by Fluent API in EF 4.1

Tags: entity-framework-4.1, fluent-interface

I've managed to read custom attributes when I use data annotation.
like following code.

```
Object[] test = propertyInfo.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(KeyAttribute), true);
```

But when I changed to use Fluent API. I couldn't read that attribute anymore.
Any idea?

Answer (score 3):

Fluent API does not set attributes. Fluent API and Attributes tell EF how to build the model.

These are two different ways to achieve the same thing. That is to build the Model.

**Edit**

If you need to retrieve the metadata such as primary keys you need to access the [MetadataWorkspace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.metadata.edm.metadataworkspace.aspx).

This [article](http://blog.cincura.net/230583-metadataworkspace-in-entity-framework/) has the details.

Comment: I really need to set the attributes with Fluent API. Is there anyway that I can read back from reflection?

Comment: I managed to get the MetadataWorkSpace through following code.
ObjectContext objContext = ((IObjectContextAdapter)_MitecsDBContext).ObjectContext;

But I'm wondering how to set the custom attributes to make following code works.

Object[] test = propertyInfo.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(KeyAttribute), true);

Comment: @Soe its in the article I linked.