# How do I get the corresponding POCO object Type from an Entity Framework Metadata EntityType object?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-code-first

I have annotated my Entity Framework Code First objects with some extra metadata, such as the [DataTypeAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.datatypeattribute.aspx) or possibly new, custom attributes.  A version of this code (from http://www.minddriven.de/index.php/technology/dot-net/web/asp-net-mvc/check-data-annotations-from-code) works well to read the attributes once I have the EF Code First POCO object's Type object.

However, I cannot figure out how to go from the MetadataWorkspace, where I find all the entities:

```
ObjectContext objContext = ((IObjectContextAdapter)this).ObjectContext;
MetadataWorkspace mw = objContext.MetadataWorkspace;
var entities = mw.GetItems<EntityType>(DataSpace.OSpace);
```

to the POCO class Types I need to reflect on the Attributes.

**How do I get from an `EntityType` to the POCO object or its proxy?  Or alternatively, how can I find all the POCO objects in the context without GetItems()?**

Relevant Links:

- [ASP.NET MVC Quick Tip: Check Data Annotations from code](http://www.minddriven.de/index.php/technology/dot-net/web/asp-net-mvc/check-data-annotations-from-code)
- [How to read Custom Attributes using reflection set by Fluent API in EF 4.1](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7104093/237091)
- [MSDN link about getting entities from proxies](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj592886.aspx)

Comment: There is (ttbomk) no way to add custom attributes to an existing type definition at runtime. In order to decorate your entities, you must do so in the source files where they are defined (or by creating an associated type to hold just the metadata/attribute annotations, in case editing the source files directly is not an option; for EF code-first you should not have this problem though).

Comment: Sorry, I was unclear.  I am not trying to add attributes, I'm just trying to read them all through reflection.  Edited to clarify, I hope.

Comment: The proxy classes should inherit from your POCO class.  I think you can just look at `proxyType.BaseType`.

Comment: @cadrell0: I don't have the proxy type either - how do I ask for those?

Answer (score 2):

There might be a direct way to do this but you can get the type from the full name

```cs
var types = from entity in entities
            select Type.GetType(entity.FullName);
```

Comment: This is not foolproof. The FullName-property does not always correspond to the assembly type name. Did not work for me.

Answer (score -1):

If I'm correct what you want - this should help as it **describes a similar problem** I posted a while ago:

[How check by unit test that properties mark as computed in ORM model?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15866272/how-check-by-unit-test-that-properties-mark-as-computed-in-orm-model/15867365#15867365)

Also check this other post which kind of summarizes it all:

[Get Model schema to programmatically create database using a provider that doesn't support CreateDatabase](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15891112/get-model-schema-to-programmatically-create-database-using-a-provider-that-doesn/15891802#15891802)
(all are earlier posts of mine)

> In short, I managed to read most of the information - but it's not
>   perfect (if I remember right, I cannot check right now) and has some
>   issues for certain situations, depends on what you need exactly).

Answer (score -1):

If it helps anyone else, this my test harness code for dumping my DbContext POCO proxies from my EF setup (specifically an Effort CSV database):

```
        MyContext ctx = new MyContext();
        var metadata = ((IObjectContextAdapter)ctx).ObjectContext.MetadataWorkspace;
        var schema = metadata.GetItems(DataSpace.SSpace).ToList();
        Dictionary<string, List<string>> tables = new Dictionary<string, List<string>>();
        Dictionary<string, System.Data.Entity.Core.Metadata.Edm.EntityType> types = new Dictionary<string, System.Data.Entity.Core.Metadata.Edm.EntityType>();
        Dictionary<string, string> table_names = new Dictionary<string, string>();
        foreach (var item in schema)
        {
            if (item.ToString().Contains("CodeFirstDatabaseSchema") && !item.ToString().Contains("_"))
            {
                string[] tableItem = item.ToString().Split('.');
                string name = tableItem[1];
                Debug.WriteLine("table_name: " + name);

                if (!tables.ContainsKey(name))
                {
                    System.Data.Entity.Core.Metadata.Edm.EntityType entity_type = item as System.Data.Entity.Core.Metadata.Edm.EntityType;
                    if (entity_type != null)
                    {
                        List<string> columns = new List<string>();
                        var members = entity_type.DeclaredMembers;
                        foreach (var member in members)
                        {
                            columns.Add(member.ToString());
                        }
                        Debug.WriteLine("columns:\n" + string.Join(",", columns));
                        tables.Add(name, columns);
                        types.Add(name, entity_type);
                        table_names.Add(name, item.MetadataProperties["TableName"].Value.ToString());
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        foreach (var table_name in tables.Keys)
        {
            List<string> columns = tables[table_name];
            System.Data.Entity.Core.Metadata.Edm.EntityType entity = types[table_name];
            string table_csv_name = table_names[table_name] + ".csv";
            Debug.WriteLine("table_csv_name: " + table_csv_name);
            var assembly_name = AssemblyName.GetAssemblyName("MyDLL.dll");
            var proxy = metadata.GetItems<System.Data.Entity.Core.Metadata.Edm.EntityType>(DataSpace.OSpace).Where(v => v.Name == table_name).FirstOrDefault();
            Type proxy_type = Type.GetType(proxy.FullName + ", " + assembly_name.FullName);
            if (proxy_type != null)
            {
                var set = ctx.Set(proxy_type);
                foreach (var row in set)
                {
                    Debug.WriteLine("row: " + row);
                }
            }
        }
```

I've then got code that dumps the DbSet objects back out to csv via reflection on the POCO properties. Note the `CodeFirstDatabaseSchema` literal above is from Effort I think, YMMV